# ¿Encadenamiento opcional ( ?.) en el atributo src y fragment(<></>)genera conflictos de resaltado en visual studio code?(Next)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vscode, next.js

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto en next, pero al momento de utilizar el atributo src={agency?.logo?.url} en la etiqueta Avatar el código posterior se formatea con el color de string, lo que hace que sea confuso de entender, se que el error es ahí porque al momento de quitar "?." (Encadenamiento opcional) y las variables posteriores se corrige

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quitando el encadenamiento opcional
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

edit: me acabo de dar cuenta que incluso cuando utilizo <></> fragment me da el mismo problema(export default se muestra con el color del
string)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

div en lugar de fragment
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Oveflow en Español ¿Que IDE estas usando? Al [agregar código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) la pregunta es mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: visual studio code, me percaté que incluso cuando uso <></>(fragment) me esta dando el mismo problema

Comment: Te da algun error de sintaxis u otro error? Porque lo mas seguro es que sea una cuestion con la extension o algo de vscode. si tienes instalado `dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring` intenta deshabilitandolo y reiniciando

Comment: @Isaac genial era eso, gracias bro.

Comment: @Isaac: Ponlo como respuesta, para que el OP pueda [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer). Joe: en ese caso era un "problema" de resaltado: no olvides ponerlo en el título.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sugerencia de @padaleiana agrego la respuesta al problema.

Para resolver el problema de resaltado de la sintaxis es necesario desinstalar o deshabilitar la extension [dzannottu.vscode-babel-coloring](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring).

La falla es porque el repositorio ya no existe y por lo tanto no tiene mantenimiento.